# Can I dock all my apps at once?

Tags: macos

I'm using a Mac at my new job and I often want to have a clear view of my desktop quickly. So far I've bound the Exposé - Desktop function to my mouse and it works okay, but the moment I want to just bring one app back from the dock, they all come back and it's frustrating.

Is there a way to show my desktop and actually put all my apps in the dock, kind of like the bottom right corner of Windows 7/8? There is this restriction that I can't install anything on my work machine. If there's nothing in Yosemite, will there be something in El Capitan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within the application that you want, just go to the application menu and click "Hide Others"(shortcut alt-cmd-H)

You can create an AppleScript and/or find third party software(like MagicPrefs) to create a shortcut for this action or an "App" in the dock that can do this.